# Double dependency dropdownlist in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel worksheet with :

- three columns A, B, C with coloured animals:
- cell D1 with dropdownlist with values: cat, dog, elephant, rabbit, lion
- cell E1 with dropdownlist with values: yellow, red, white

Example data are like below:

```
         A          B           C
    ---------------------------------------------------------
1   |   cat         yellow      my loved yellow cat
1   |   cat         yellow      my hated yellow cat
2   |   cat         red         my favourite red cat
3   |   dog         white       ugly white dog
4   |   dog         white       elegant white dog
5   |   elephant    white       beauty white elephant
6   |   elephant    yellow      tiny yellow elephant
7   |   rabbit      red         small red rabbit
8   |   lion        red         red lion for my son
9   |   lion        white       my pet lion white
```

Now in cell F1 I need to have the dropdown list dependent on values selected in cells in D1 and E1. So If you will select in D1 cat and in E1 yellow, you should have in F1 two options to select:

- my loved yellow cat
- my hated yellow cat

The solutions with one dependent column I do it:
Data -> Validation -> List -> in formula I paste:

=OFFSET($C$1,MATCH(D1,$A$1:$A$9,0)-1,0,COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,D1),1)

But this filter only by animals and I have in dropdown three cats: my loved yellow cat, my hated yellow cat, my favourite red cat. But I need only yellow cats! Is method to create it like desctibed below?

Comment: Perhaps [this youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIJbcBBH88M&list=PLmHVyfmcRKywYhC1Q9eZqR7D-_cdiwl6y) playlist will help/ guide

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/02/22/vlookup-multiple-values-excel/#vlookup-multiple-matches-rows), there something very similar.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C1:C10, SMALL(IF(1=((--(D1=A1:A10))*(--(E1=B1:B10))), ROW(C1:C10),""), ROW())),"")
```